# Showing Groups and Injectivity of Group Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Let $f: G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ be a group homomorphism, and let $K$ = {$g | f(g) = e_2$}, where $e_2$ is the identity of $G_2$. **1)** Show that $K$ is a group. **2)**  Show that if $K$ = {$e_1$}, then $f$ is injective.

This is what I have:

1) Kinda lost on this one. I know the axioms of a group, but I'm not sure how to apply it to $K$. I would have to show that the identity exists in $K$, the existence of inverses in $K$, and associativity in $K$, right?

2) Since $K$ = {$e_1$}, we only have 1 element, $e_1$, that maps to $e_2$. $0 \rightarrow 0$ is an injective mapping, and therefore $f$ is injective if $K$ = {$e_1$}.

Any help on this would be tremendously helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Your proof of (2) looks incomplete to me; you need to prove that $f$ is injective for every mapping from $G_1$ to $G_2$, not just for $e_1 \mapsto e_2$.

Comment: That's what I'm lost on. I don't see how to "expand" $0 \mapsto 0$ to other elements of $G_1$.

Comment: You can use $K = \{e_1\}$ to prove that for any $g,h \in G_1$, if $f(g) = f(h)$, then $g = h$. Possibly-too-big-of-a-hint: what is $f(g) - f(h)$, and what does that tell you about $g - h$ (using the fact that $K = \{e_1\}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome Problem! This one is fun.

1. Since $f$ is a homomorphism, $f(e_1) = e_2$, so $e_1 \in K$.

   For any $a,b \in K$, we have $f(ab) = f(a)f(b) = e_2e_2 = e_2$, so $ab \in K$, giving us closure.

   We have associativity because multiplication in $K$ works the same way as in $G_1$.

   For any $a \in K$, $f(aa^{-1}) = e_2 = f(a)f(a^{-1}) = e_2f(a^{-1})$, so $f(a^{-1}) = e_2$ and thus $a^{-1} \in K$.

   Thus K is a Group!
2. Suppose, for some $g,h \in G$, that $f(g) = f(h)$. Then $f(g) = f(g)f(h^{-1})f(h) = f(gh^{-1})f(h)$. But f(g) = f(h), so $f(gh^{-1}) = e_2$. Then $gh^{-1} \in K$, so $gh^{-1} = e_1$. Then $g = h$. Thus, $f$ is injective.

Any questions? I'm happy to clarify in comments.

Comment: How does $g = h$ translate to injectivity?

Comment: Injectivity is almost always proven by assuming $f(g) = f(h)$, then showing $ g = h$.

Comment: Because Injectivity by definition means that if two elements in the domain map to the same element in the codomain, they must have been the same thing.

Comment: Ohh right, I forgot about that definition. That actually makes it so much clearer. Thank you!